# docker run bash script cannot exit

Tags: shell, docker, jenkins

In my CI system，jenkins execute shell script to build ...
The script like this:

```
docker run -d --rm -v /code-path:/tmp docker-iamge-name sh -c " \
    cd /tmp ;\
    mkdir build ;\
    cd build ;\
    cmake ../ ;\
    make ;\
    ./unit-test-execute-file1 ;\
    ...
"
```

But when there are errors in code file, make command exits, and then next command(./unit-test-execute-file1) is executed. Since `make` failed, so unit-test-execute-file is not generated, and next command also fails... In the end, script exit with code 0, and Jenkins shows build is successful..

Can someone help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `set -e` as the first line in the bash script if you want that script should exit at any point the script fails.

Your run statement would look like:

```
docker run -d --rm -v /code-path:/tmp docker-iamge-name sh -c " \
    set -e ;\
    cd /tmp ;\
    mkdir build ;\
    cd build ;\
    cmake ../ ;\
    make ;\
    ./unit-test-execute-file1 ;\
    ...
"
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rely on `set -e` (which really is *not* reliable, at least not without fully understanding all the exceptions that *don't* exit the shel), be explicit about which commands to run. In this case, you can simply chain the commands together with `&&`, so that each command only runs if the previous command succeeds. The exit status of the chain is the exit status of the last command to run (e.g., if `cd build` fails, its exit status is the exit status of `sh -c`).

```
docker run -d --rm -v /code-path:/tmp docker-iamge-name sh -c "
  cd /tmp &&
  mkdir build &&
  cd build &&
  cmake ../ &&
  make &&
  ./unit-test-execute-file1 &&
  ...
"
```